# Swift - Accessing an array inside a swift class causes a crash in SwiftData

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift-data

I'm using Swift and SwiftData. I have a class called Story and inside that class an array of another class called StoryBox.

I instantiate a Story with a StoryBox array and pass it to a view and try to display its content.

I can display the String of the Story object but if I add the lines to try to access the contents of the any element of the StoryBox array inside it I get an error stating:

"Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1c3c6203c)" on the

```
return self.getValue(forKey: \.storyBoxArray)
```

This is autogenerated code from the SwiftData implementation.

[image: Error in Xcode when loading view]

**Classes:**

Story:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@Model
class Story{
    
    let id = UUID()
    var storyTitle: String
    var storyTitleImage: Data
    var storyBoxArray: [StoryBox]
    
    
    init(storyTitle: String, storyTitleImage: Data, storyBoxArray: [StoryBox]) {
        self.storyTitle = storyTitle
        self.storyTitleImage = storyTitleImage
        self.storyBoxArray = storyBoxArray
    }

}
```

StoryBox:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@Model
class StoryBox {
    
    let id = UUID()
    var storyImage: Data
    var storyIndex: Int
    var storyIsCompleted: Bool
    var storyText: String
    
    init(storyImage: Data, storyIndex: Int, storyIsCompleted: Bool, storyText: String) {
        self.storyImage = storyImage
        self.storyIndex = storyIndex
        self.storyIsCompleted = storyIsCompleted
        self.storyText = storyText
    }
}
```

View:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct TempNewView: View {
    @State var CurrentStory: Story
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(CurrentStory.storyTitle)")
        let myImage = UIImage(data: CurrentStory.storyTitleImage)
        Image(uiImage: myImage!)

        let myImage2 = UIImage(data: CurrentStory.storyBoxArray[0].storyImage)
        Image(uiImage: myImage2!)
        
    }
}
```

The error occurs when I try to access the Data here:

```
let myImage2 = UIImage(data: CurrentStory.storyBoxArray[0].storyImage)
    Image(uiImage: myImage2!)
```

It also crashes the Preview.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

This is the call for the view

```
TempNewView(CurrentStory: Story(storyTitle: "Story Title_Preview", storyTitleImage: (UIImage(systemName: "5.lane")?.pngData())!, storyBoxArray: preview_createStoryBoxes(number: 6)))
```

This is the method which generates the array of StoryBox

```
func preview_createStoryBoxes(number: Int)->[StoryBox]{
var StoryData = [StoryBox]()
for i in 0...number {
    StoryData.append(StoryBox(storyImage: UIImage(systemName: "\(i).circle")!.pngData()!, storyIndex: i, storyIsCompleted: false, storyText: "\(i): The quick fox jumps over the lazy dog"))
}
return StoryData
```

}

Comment: I suggest you **do not** use `!` in your code. Also **do not** use an index without at least checking it, eg `if CurrentStory.storyBoxArray.count > 0 {...}`. "CurrentStory.storyBoxArray[0]" means the `first` element of the array, so if the array is empty, the code will crash.

Comment: Hi @workingdogsupportUkraine Thanks for the suggestions. Both absolutely valid. 
In this case I know there is definitely data and an element as I have just instantiated them so it’s safe.

Comment: No it is not safe, as you can tell by the crash. Try
 `if CurrentStory.storyBoxArray.count > 0 {...} else { Image(systemName: "info") }`
 Let us know if it crashes and if the `info` is displayed. The crash could also be due to the data,
 in that case use `if let myImage2 = UIImage(data: CurrentStory.storyBoxArray[0].storyImage) {
 Image(uiImage: myImage2) }`

Comment: The error is dependent on how you create and insert your objects but that part of the code is missing from the question.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I added your code above and it looks like it's crashing when it's trying to access the count of `storyBoxArray`. I'm guessing then my StoryBox array is not being instantiated as I expected.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I added the call to the view and the method which generates the StoryBox array. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftData is a bit sensitive to how you create objects and relationship, specially when all objects are new. The safest way I found is to create an object that is part of the relationship, insert it into the model context and then assign the object(s) that is the other part of the relationship.

So the line

```
TempNewView(CurrentStory: Story(storyTitle: "Story Title_Preview", storyTitleImage: (UIImage(systemName: "5.lane")?.pngData())!, storyBoxArray: preview_createStoryBoxes(number: 6)))
```

should be split up into

```
let story = Story(storyTitle: "Story Title_Preview", storyTitleImage: (UIImage(systemName: "5.lane")?.pngData())!, storyBoxArray: [])

modelContext.insert(story)
story.storyBoxArray = preview_createStoryBoxes(number: 6))) //or use append
```

And then call the view with `story`

Comment: This has resolved my issue. Thank you. Do you know why SwiftData acts like this?

Comment: It’s most likely a bug but it’s also expected that you insert the objects in the model context if you want to persist them. Don’t forget to mark this as accepted if it has resolved your issue

Comment: I hope it gets fixed but this work around also makes it more clear anyway. Marked as the answer. Thanks for your help.